# Separately display Odd and Even array data in a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, laravel-4

```
<?php $ctr = 0; ?>
@foreach($level1['Weapons'] as $key => $header)
   @if($ctr% == 0) 
      <div class="left">
   @endif
   @if($ctr% == 1) 
      <div class="right">
   @endif
      <ul>
         <li>
            <span class="ability">{{$key}}</span><br>
            <p class="ability-desc">{{$header['desc']}}</p>
         </li>
       </ul>

       @if($ctr == 8 || $ctr == 7) 
         </div>
       @endif

       <?php $ctr++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Array:

```
 'level1' =>
    array (    
 'Weapons' =>
    array (
      'Misfortune' =>
      array (
        'desc' => 'You can make any person fall',
      ),
      'Sorrow' =>
      array (
        'desc' => 'You can make a person cry just by looking at them',
      ),
      'Stink' =>
      array (
        'desc' => 'No living person can endure your fart',
      ),
      'Harden' =>
      array (
        'desc' => 'You can make soft things hard, even water',
      ),
```

I have a foreach which will list all the item from the array description. My problem is I created an if statement to assign the values from ODD and EVEN array element to a div which will separate them into left and right according to result. I notice that the result only seems to display on the left side. How do I re-arrange or make an if statement that will satisfy my idea. I hope this question made sense.

Comment: [php modulo operator - syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) Its always best to check the manual before asking a question

Comment: I would suggest you do this via CSS e.g. `div:nth-child(odd) { float: left; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build up 2 strings in your loop and then just echo them out after your loop.  Been a while since I did php so there may be a few syntax errors but you should get the general idea:

```html
<?php 
  $ctr = 0; 
  $leftLi = "";
  $rightLi = "";
  
  foreach($level1['Weapons'] as $key => $header)
  {
    if ($ctr % 2 == 0)
    {
        $leftLi += MakeLi($key, $header['desc']);
    } else {
        $rightLi += MakeLi($key, $header['desc']);
    }
    
    $ctr++;
  }
  
  function MakeLi($key, $headerText)
  {
      return "
    <li>
      <span class=\"ability\">" . $key . "</span><br>
      <p class=\"ability-desc\">" . $headerText . "</p>
    </li>";
  }
?>



<div class="left">
  <ul>
    <?php echo $leftLi; ?>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <ul>
    <?php echo $rightLi; ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this one works, I just made some adjustments so it could fit my design.